# Is it possible to get crash logs from apps distributed with enterprise license?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, crash-reports

Our company distributes apps with Enterprises license, so client creates in their developer program the Bundle ID, we compile it, send them.

Is it possible get in a way crash logs i.e. with Crashlytics?

Is it worth to use any 3rd party crash reporting system? What advantage they offer compare Apple internal crash reporting?

One sure, from Apple we do not get crash logs to Xcode, because we do not own Bundle ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple only provides crash logs for apps that are distributed via the App Store (and where users have opted-in to providing information to developers).

It is not a question of who "owns" the bundle id.  With enterprise apps there is no "ownership" of a bundle ID since there is no App Store Connect record.

The app has a bundle ID to identify it and it is recommended that you stick with a "reverse-DNS" value in order to ensure uniqueness.

To get crash reports for an enterprise app you will need to use a third-party crash reporting solution.

Comment: Thanks! Which crash reporting tool you use the most?

Comment: I have used Crashlytics which is part of Firebase, but I can't say if it is better or worse than others.

Answer (score 4):

we get crash report using only third party library like crashlytics.  And apple never provide crash log report.
   Yes it is worth to use crash reporting system.

Comment: Are you distributing with enterprise license? So bundle ID is not yours?